# Unable to play audio using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, audio

I am not a developer so I hope you will bear with me. I am setting up my own website but have zero experience with html and JavaScript. I am learning by downloading demo software. For the most part I could run the demos on my own site. There is one problem. I cannot play audio. Show me the code you say. Console shows no errors. Access.log shows files being downloaded.

Not Working, shows play button but click does nothing.

```html
<html>
  <body>
     <audio src="bell.ogg" id="player" loop>Get an HTML5 browser!</audio>
     <form id="interface">
             <input type="button" value="Play" 
              ↪onclick="PlayPause()" id="playpause"/>
     </form>
     <script type="text/javascript">
     var audioPlayer = document.getElementById("player");

     function PlayPause()
     {
         if (audioPlayer.paused)
         {
             audioPlayer.play();
             document.getElementById("playpause").value = "Pause";
         }
         else
         {
             audioPlayer.pause();
             document.getElementById("playpause").value = "Play"; 
         }
     }
     </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Working

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>

    <audio controls>
      <source src="bell.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
      <source src="bell.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You probably want to remove the character in front of the onclick: `↪on`

Comment: Try to add preload="auto" attribute with audio element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code works if you remove the weird carriage return character from `↪onclick="PlayPause()"` and the file exists

```js
var audioPlayer = document.getElementById("player");

function PlayPause() {
  if (audioPlayer.paused) {
    audioPlayer.play();
    document.getElementById("playpause").value = "Pause";
  } else {
    audioPlayer.pause();
    document.getElementById("playpause").value = "Play";
  }
}
```

```html
<audio src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/34/Sound_Effect_-_Door_Bell.ogg" id="player" loop>Get an HTML5 browser!</audio>
<form id="interface">
  <input type="button" value="Play" onclick="PlayPause()" id="playpause" />
</form>
```

Comment: That fixed the demo code I had copied. That error sent me off in the wrong direction. I wanted a simple script that downloaded and played an audio file. I went down that road because a much larger webrtc demo that I found would not play the notification sound on an incoming call. So I am no farther ahead on that one. I couild see by the access.log that the media was downloaded but not playing. After playing around some more I found that setting a web audio create audio context event in the debugger and reloading twice would allow the notification to play.